# Test a Django model that uses request.user in save_model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model that overrides `save_model` in order to automatically save the current authenticated user into a field on save.

The question is, how in a unit test can I test the creation of this model, without having to go through a view?

The model:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        self.prevent_update()

        if not obj.pk:
            # Only set added_by during the first save.

            obj.created = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

The test just wants to set up `SomeClass` before doing some other stuff.

```
class SomeClassTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.assertTrue(request.user)
        SomeClass.objects.create(name="abc")
```

I know that there is a request getting set up automatically, since `request.user` doesn't fail with `request` being `None`; instead, the query constraint fails because the user is null. How do I set a user on the request that appears to have been passed into `save_model`

Alternatively, I know I can setup a request using `RequestFactory` and generate a user. In that case, how do I get that into the test so that the `SomeClass.objects.create` actually sees it.

Comment: `save_model` is something for a `ModelAdmin`, not for a `Model`. `Model`s are *request-unaware*.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I realised that I had copied and pasted badly, placing `save_model` into a model. This and my amateurish abilities with Django caused all kinds of confusion. So the fact that `request.user` was not failing was because it was never called.

I am now correctly overriding the `save` method in the model, and the `save_model` method in the admin, which passes the correct details to the model for it to save.